# Matplotlib cannot plot DateTime Series with only NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame `dtf` with a column `Data`...

```
print(dft.Date)
print(type(dft))
print(type(dft.iloc[0]["Date"]))

1340    2018-01-04 00:06:58
1341    2018-01-04 00:17:18
1342    2018-01-04 00:27:38
1343    2018-01-04 00:37:59
1344    2018-01-04 00:48:19
1345    2018-01-04 00:58:41
1346    2018-01-04 01:09:01
1347    2018-01-04 01:19:21
1348    2018-01-04 01:29:41
1349    2018-01-04 01:40:02
Name: Date, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

...and a column of values `X` sometimes with many `np.NaN` values. I want to be flexible and plot the graph (with nothing in it) even though there are only `np.NaN` in the column `X`. Everything works fine when there is **at least** one not-`np.NaN` value present:

```
dft["X"] = np.array([1] + [np.NaN for i in range(9)])

plt.plot(dft.Date, dft.X)   #  works as expected
```

But as soon as there are **only** `np.NaN` present and I try to plot:

```
dft["X"] = np.array([np.NaN for i in range(10)])

plt.plot(dft.Date, dft.X)
```

.. I get the following error:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1ba20c7f128>]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    236 
    237     if 'png' in formats:
--> 238         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    239     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    120 
    121     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 122     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    123     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    124     if fmt == 'svg':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2214                     orientation=orientation,
   2215                     dryrun=True,
-> 2216                     **kwargs)
   2217                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2218                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    428             # if toolbar:
    429             #     toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
--> 430             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    431         finally:
    432             # if toolbar:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1297 
   1298             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1299                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1300 
   1301             renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2435             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2436 
-> 2437         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2438 
   2439         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1131         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1132 
-> 1133         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1134         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1135                                                                 renderer)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    972 
    973         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 974         tick_tups = list(self.iter_ticks())
    975         if self._smart_bounds and tick_tups:
    976             # handle inverted limits

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in iter_ticks(self)
    915         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    916         """
--> 917         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    918         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    919         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in __call__(self)
   1095     def __call__(self):
   1096         'Return the locations of the ticks'
-> 1097         self.refresh()
   1098         return self._locator()
   1099 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in refresh(self)
   1115     def refresh(self):
   1116         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1117         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1118         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1119 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
    873             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    874 
--> 875         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
    876 
    877     def _get_unit(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    464         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    465     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 466         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    467     else:
    468         x = np.asarray(x)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    277 
    278     ix = int(x)
--> 279     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    280 
    281     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1ba20c5c630>
```

I already tried to convert the `Date` column according to [this post](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html) and converting `Date` by using `dft.Date.astype('O')` and many other workarounds. Nothing worked.

I don't want to drop or fill the NaNs.

Comment: I don't understand what such a plot should look like?

Comment: You are literally telling it to plot nothing, so there is nothing to show. What do you expect to happen when you plot such column? Do you expect to see some kind of a figure? Or do you want to skip plotting this column? Or something completely different

Comment: I would like to see the same result as if you were to do this:
`a = {"one":[1,2,4], "two":[np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]}`
`df = pd.DataFrame(a)`
`df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True, sharey=True)`
so just a blank graph.